# Operation returns a scalar value when a vector of values is expected

Tags: matlab, vector, division, scalar

I'm evaluating a simple function:

```
y = (2*x)/sqrt( 1 + x.^2 );
```

Where `x` is a vector with about 100 values in it. However, MATLAB makes `y` equal to a single scalar value in this instance. If I do:

```
y = 2*x;
```

I get a vector of values in `y` as expected. If I do:

```
y = x.^2;
```

I *also* get a vector of values in `y` as expected.

Why is the above equation `y = (2*x)/sqrt( 1 + x.^2 );` giving a single value and not a vector of values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation `B/A` (given `B = 2*x` and `A = sqrt(1+x.^2)`) will attempt to perform [matrix right division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mrdivide.html), which for a row vector `x` will be the solution in the least squares sense to the system of equations `yA = B`, which results in a scalar value for `y`.

For [element-wise array division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html), perform the operation `B./A` instead (note the `.`).